# What kind of tests should run on the CI server?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration

Currently, our unit tests are committed along with the application code and executed by a build bot job on each commit. Likewise, code coverage is calculated. However, both UTs and coverage are - or can be - conducted by the developers before they commit new features to the repository, so the CI process does not seem to add any value.

What kind of tests do you suggest should be executed on the CI server which are *not* executed by the developer's prior to commit?

Answer (score 3):

> so the CI process does not seem to add any value

No?

- What happens if a developer doesn't run the tests before committing?
- What happens if a developer commits a change which conflicts with a change committed by another developer?
- What happens if the tests pass on the developer's machine but not on other machines?
- What happens if another developer has changed a test?
- ...

CI isn't "continuous testing", it's "continuous *integration*".  The need to run the tests as part of the integration build is to validate that the changes committed can successfully *integrate* with what's already there.  Whether or not the tests passed on the developer's local potentially-non-integrated workstation is immaterial.

The unit tests (*any* reasonably fast automated tests, really) should be executed by the CI server to validate the current state of the build.  That state may be different than what is on one individual developer's workstation.

They may be the same tests which were just run by the developer moments prior.  But the context in which the tests run is physically different and the need to run them is semantically different.  Unless you're being charged by the clock cycle, there's no reason to omit running tests.

Answer (score 1):

David raises very good points.  One thing that he didn't mention though is that automated testing in a continuously integrated environment can be even more powerful when it goes beyond unit tests.  The CI process allows you to run integration and system level tests that would be too expensive to run on a dev box.  For example, you may have unit tests for your persistence layer that run against an in-memory database.  Your CI server however can run these same automated tests against a snapshot of your production database.

Comment: I alluded to that with, "any reasonably fast automated tests, really."  The key here isn't really the kind of tests being run, but the time it takes them to run.  Integration tests with heavy resource dependencies have a risk of taking long enough to run that multiple source commits can happen in the meantime, which not only queues up ever-increasing work for the server but begs the question of what to do with check-in B if check-in A hasn't been validated yet, which can have disruptive consequences.  Longer-running tests can often be better left for nightly builds.

Comment: @David There's no rule that says every test has to run at the same time.  You could have 500 automated tests that each run independently in addition to the commit-specific unit and smoke tests.  When one fails, the system rolls back everything that patched after its last success whether it was 30 seconds ago or 30 minutes.  It's better than only having unit tests and finding out about the regression when customers start calling, or worse.  The idea is that the CI environment can be much closer to prod than a dev box, and your automated test suite can take advantage of this.

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with previous posts, as Unit testing is *mostly* done by devs. So tests that should be executed as part of the  CI process  is pretty much opinion based. Depending of the goals of the team/project.

The thing that is also important is that CI (server) gives you a *separate testing environment*. So your test effort and execution can run independent. Your test are executed in a clone of the production environment.

In my expirience I've used CI server mostly for System,Integration,  Functional, Regression testing and [UAT](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/3887/user-acceptance-testing-uat).